Match physical modem device with wireless interface wwan in ubuntu
I have two different modems from the same vendor: Quectel EC25 and Quectel RM500Q. The problem arises when the PC box where they are plugged starts. Sometimes the Quectel EC25 takes the wwan0 which implies taking the ttyUSB0/1/2/3 and the QuectelRM500Q the wwan1 which implies taking the ttyUSB4/5/6/7 and other times it is just the opposite: QuectelEC25 with wwan1 and ttyUSB4/5/6/7 and QuectelRM500Q with wwan0 and ttyUSB0/1/2/3. Being the starting different it is not possible to configure each modem due to one modem has a SIM from one network operator and th e other one another.
I tried to match the wireless interface and the modem with a rule of udev (/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules):
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2c7c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0800", NAME="wwan0" 
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2c7c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0125", NAME="wwan1"

But it didn't work.
